# Optional fields 2 in JabRef 3.1 are not configurable

Tags: jabref

Running JabRef 3.1 on MacOs X 10.11 in Biblatex mode

The runner Optional fields 2 is empty. When trying to configure e.g. entry type Book, I can delete field names from either Required fields or Optional fields, but all changes done to Optional fields 2 are lost immediately after clicking Apply/OK.
I would like to populate it with some own fields, because Optional fields is so full of different fields that it demands scrolling.

I would remember that I was able to change fields in Optional field 2 back in version 2.7 (?), but have not been able to do this afterwards.

Comment: This is more an implementation issue than a configuration issue. Please ask your question at https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues. I checked http://jabref.sourceforge.net/revisionhistory.php and it reads at "Version 2.11 beta"; "Fixes bug that prevented the secondary optional fields to update properly in the "Customize entry fields" dialog (in BibLatex mode)". Seems to be a regression.